# Change fields with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'd like to change some contact form fields with jquery.
That's the normal code:

```
<label for="avia_3_1">Nome <abbr class="required" title="Richiesto">*</abbr></label>
```

That's the jquery I'm using. I have a combobox, the name of the label should change based on the user selected item. It works, but the tag `<abbr>` disappear.

```
//$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
$("#avia_1_1").change(function(){
    switch($("#avia_1_1").val()){
        case "Privato":
            $("label[for='avia_3_1']").text("Nome");
            $("abbr[title='Richiesto']").text("*");
        break;

        case "Azienda":
            $("label[for='avia_3_1']").text("Ragione Sociale");
            $("abbr[title='Richiesto']").text("*");
        break;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: that's why abbr is removed... $("label[for='avia_3_1']").text("Nome");

Comment: How can I change that text, but leave abbr there?

Comment: Check my aswer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.html()` instead of `.text()`. Check updated script below..

```
//$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#avia_1_1").change(function(){
        switch($("#avia_1_1").val()){
            case "Privato":
                $("label[for='avia_3_1']").html('Nome<abbr class="required" title="Richiesto">*</abbr>');
            break;

            case "Azienda":
                $("label[for='avia_3_1']").html('Ragione Sociale<abbr class="required" title="Richiesto">*</abbr>');
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `<abbr>` tag is inside the `<label>` tag. You will have to create `<abbr>` on every change event. Below is a sample code that you can use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#avia_1_1").change(function() {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case "Privato":
        $("label[for='avia_3_1']").text("Nome");
        $("abbr[title='Richiesto']").text("*");
        break;

      case "Azienda":
        $("label[for='avia_3_1']").text("Ragione Sociale");
        $("abbr[title='Richiesto']").text("*");
        break;
    }
    $('<abbr />', {
      "class": 'required',
      'title': 'Richiesto'
    }).appendTo($(this));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's why abbr is removed... `$("label[for='avia_3_1']").text("Nome")`;
Try this:

```
 $("label[for='avia_3_1']").html("Nome <abbr class='required' title='Richiesto'>*</abbr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is removed because .text("") removes the content of the element.

you can try this.

```
$("label[for='avia_3_1']").html('Nome'+ '<abbr class="required" title="Richiesto">*</abbr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#avia_1_1").change(function(){
switch($("#avia_1_1").val()){
    case "Privato":
        $("label[for='avia_3_1']").html('Nome <abbr class="required" title="Richiesto">*</abbr>');
    break;

    case "Azienda":
        $("label[for='avia_3_1']").html('Ragione Sociale <abbr class="required" title="Richiesto">*</abbr>');
    break;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are changing value of label, abbr is inside label so it remove the abbr and update with selected value removing abbr.

```
<select id="avia_1_1" name="test">
  <option value="Privato">Privato</option>
  <option vaue="Azienda">Azienda</option>
</select>

<label for="avia_3_1">Nome </label>
<abbr class="required" title="Richiesto">*</abbr>

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
$("#avia_1_1").change(function(){
    switch($("#avia_1_1").val()){
        case "Privato":
            $("label[for='avia_3_1']").text("Nome");
            $("abbr[title='Richiesto']").text("*");
        break;

        case "Azienda":
            $("label[for='avia_3_1']").text("Ragione Sociale");
            $("abbr[title='Richiesto']").text("*");
        break;
    }
});
});
```

[Working Demo](https://codepen.io/gudboisgn/pen/Evayep)